# How to configure device type in bluethooth advertising package?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I'm developing a custom bluetooth keyboard. It works now smoothly, but there's one thing I can't figure out. In macOS bluetooth settings page, the icon doesn't properly imply its device type. AirPods Pro and Logitech M590 mouse do the job well.

[image]

Going through the system information, both AirPods Pro and Logitech M590 have a **minor type** field in its device information. I believe it's sent to Macbook via the device bluetooth advertising.

[image]

My keyboard is developed on top of an nRF52832 module. I'm not very familiar with NRF SDK, this is my first attempt. How can I add such information to my device? Any links to the doc or sample code would help.

Comment: THis was discussed 4 years ago in the nordic devzone: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/44826/setting-class-of-device Not sure what the status is now regarding a COD field, but there is also a mention of a manual way

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan your comment is very helpful. Now I found there is a list of pre-defined macros https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.s132.api.v6.1.0%2Fgroup___b_l_e___a_p_p_e_a_r_a_n_c_e_s.html

Comment: Please share your findings as an answer once you figure it out completely :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great thanks to @MichaelKotzjan who provides the helpful information.

The answer is kinda simple (yeah I'm a newbie for nRF). Just call [`sd_ble_gap_appearance_set`](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.s132.api.v6.1.0%2Fgroup___b_l_e___g_a_p___f_u_n_c_t_i_o_n_s.html) method in your GAP initialization, passing [`BLE_APPEARANCE_HID_KEYBOARD`](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.s132.api.v6.1.0%2Fgroup___b_l_e___a_p_p_e_a_r_a_n_c_e_s.html) as the argument.

Here's a [sample](https://github.com/NordicPlayground/nRF52-Bluetooth-Course/blob/master/main.c#L316). You can definitely pass another macro depending on the device you're developing.

```c
static void gap_params_init(void)
{
    // some code

    err_code = sd_ble_gap_appearance_set(BLE_APPEARANCE_HID_KEYBOARD);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

    // some code
}
```

Now I get the proper icon

[image]